# How to change data in filds generated by symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('date', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
        ))
        ->add('etat')
        ->add('tt')
        ->add('idClient')
        ->add('idComercial')
        ->add('idMission')
    ;
}
```

(idMission)  in my Twig template , return all missions , but i want to personalize missions ( check if mission is old or not , if is old don't show it )

I'am sorry for my English 
:)
thnaks for help

Comment: you can add some condition at twig so that id don't show old mission.

Comment: i can't do that from my formType ? !

Comment: how are you printing all missions?

Comment: in my twig template like this 
  `<div class="form-group">
                            {{ form_label(form.idMission, 'Mission : ',{ 'attr': {'class': 'control-label'} }) }}
                            {{ form_widget(form.idMission, { 'attr' : {'class': 'form-control','required' :'required'}} ) }}
                        </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hallelujah :)

It works, I fond the solution [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities)

The solution is to use query_builder in your FormType:

```
 ->add('idMission' ,'entity', array(
            'class' => 'PFEBundle:Mission',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->where('u.date > :now')
                    ->setParameter('now', new \DateTime('now'));
            },))
    ;
```